# CMapStringToString can't handle Unicode?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, mfc

I have a CMapStringToString that I fill with unicode characters.

```
m_oMap.SetAt( CString(bstrID), CString(bstrText));
```

`bstrText` is a BSTR containing unicode characters that are actually stored correctly (Cyrillic symbols, Japanese symbols, etc.). At this point `bstrText` contains e.g. "Калибровка".

However, if I try to retrieve the symbols the unicode encoding seems to be lost:

```
BOOL b = m_oMap.Lookup((LPCTSTR)key, rValue); // key and value are CString&
```

After this line `rValue` e.g. only contains "??????????" instead of "Калибровка".

What is happening here?

Comment: So what *are* your UNICODE settings?

Comment: My projects are all set to use Unicode character set.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `CStringW` (in place of `CString`)? And what's up with that `(LPCTSTR)` cast anyway? That's a C-style cast, to a generic-text mapped character string. Both of these are highly questionable. If your code doesn't compile without the cast, you should fix the bug instead of silencing the compiler.

Comment: Does `Lookup` return `TRUE`? Usually the MFC container classes are pretty mature and stable, so while I wouldn't exclude bugs there _a priori_, I'd focus on _your_ code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple MFC dialog-based application with VS2015, added a string  resource `IDS_TEST_UNICODE` containing your Unicode string, and the following MFC code works fine:

```
void CTestMfcApp1Dlg::OnBnClickedButtonTest1()
{
    CMapStringToString m;

    CString value(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDS_TEST_UNICODE));
    m.SetAt(CString(L"MyKey"), value);

    CString readValue;
    VERIFY( m.Lookup(L"MyKey", readValue) );
    VERIFY(readValue == value);
}
```

as you can note from the screenshot at the bottom.

May it be just possible that `CMapStringToString` works fine in your case as well, and instead you are having problems just *visualizing* the content of the value string retrieved from the map?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: `CString value((LPCTSTR)IDS_TEST_UNICODE);` should use the [MAKEINTRESOURCE macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) instead (I know, the [CString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) documentation uses the very same cast, but there's no reason to repeat this). As an aside, you could also define `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` to disable inadvertent Unicode ↔ ANSI conversions.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I'll accept this as the solution and point out that there was a referenced project in my solution that was not yet changed to support Unicode.